# Can we lock this old, below-standard but interesting question?

Tags: discussion

I came across this question today from a Google search involving Python and shebangs: [What is the best Python library module skeleton code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2387272/2615940)

I think one look at the title is enough to see that it qualifies for the "Primarily Opinion-Based" close reason. If you go look at it, you'll see that the variety of different perspectives in the answers and comments makes it a good example of why we have that close reason. Since it could be found by anyone searching for Python and shebang together, I think it has enough visibility to warrant some action on it.

However, I also found it very interesting to read through the different examples and learned a few things. I'd hate to see something that I learned from go away.

Does this question qualify for a historical lock, or is that normally reserved for questions that have higher demonstrated value? Is there someone with high enough rep willing to put a lock on it?

(By demonstrated value, I mean upvotes. Posts I've seen with a historical lock seem to usually have hundreds of upvotes, while this only has 30.)

Comment: I don't honestly thing this is that useful. Besides the fact that the question was edited to provide a summary that disagrees with the answers it summarizes (and the answers don't provide their rationale), if we lose information that promotes non-ReST formatting in docstrings, suggests that most editors can't handle UTF-8, and suggests that every module should be runnable as a script, that explicitly ignores packages, that suggests `#!/usr/bin/env python` with no comment on Python 3 or on letting `setuptools` shebang for you… I don't think we've lost much.

Comment: Fair enough. The issues you mentioned hadn't occurred to me. In that case, let's close it instead, because I certainly don't think it should stick around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rereading it a few hours later with the comments on this question in mind, I've changed my mind about it. I no longer think it's worth keeping around.

I've flagged it for closure.